# How can I use MSBuild to deploy to a folder in TeamCity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, teamcity

On my local dev machine this works perfectly:

```
msbuild project.name.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="c:\proyectos\folder1\deploy" /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

I'm trying to configure a Build step in TeamCity with MSBuild, in the "Command line parameters" I'm putting this:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="c:\proyectos\folder1\deploy" /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

It runs, no errors are displayed, but files are not copied to "c:\proyectos\folder1\deploy"

Edit: I'm having the same issues with MSBuild on the command prompt, so it's not teamcity. My local dev machine is on windows 7 and the server is windows 2003

Comment: What does the stuff doing the copying look like? If it errors, will it break the build? If not, doing /v:diag will show the individual steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run with `/v:d` or `v:diag` to get logging.

(Get it working local first but... In TeamCity, view the agent in the console and look at the agent detail logs for similar such logs (or just pass the same `/v:` flag to MSBuild via TeamCity))

Comment: thanks, after I thought the problem was with teamcity but the issue was with msbuild itself. I figured out I had to install visual studio on the server!

Comment: @hminaya: Glad you're sorted. Dont like hearing about people taking nuclear options like putting VS on the server though - in general you just need to put the appropriate .targets files, but then I dont know anything about what you're __actually__ doing though!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to ensure that the user running the "TeamCity Build Agent Service" has write access to the relevant directories.

(FWIW, I believe the LocalSystem account has different group memberships in Server 2003 and Windows 7.  We run all of our TeamCity build agents under their own "teamcity" accounts to more explicitly control permissions and allow access to network shares.)

Comment: As long as you're not swallowing errors, the error message may lead to this. Step one is find out what's wrong, not start guessing?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Visual Studio 2010 DOES fix this problem. But, you can also fix it by copying the appropriate build targets to your machine.  Typically, on your dev machine they'll be at **(Or take away the (x86) for 32 bit machines)**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web
```

In there you'll find a bunch of Microsoft.Web.Publishing.* targets.

Just copy those over to the equivalent location on your build machine and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Web deploy tool through web platform in the server works for me. Actually visual studio installation installs web deploy, It might be the reason why it works for @himinaya.